# DOM not updating until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I have an asynchronous method that calls a web api to retrieve json data.

I then use the json data to fill in a few `' boxes. However, the values do not appear in the text boxes until I refresh the page?

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <h1 id="OrderNameHeader"></h1>

    <div class="dataitemdiv">
        <p class="dataitemlabel">Quantity:</p>
        <input id="quantitytb" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="dataitemtextbox" />
    </div>

    <div class="dataitemdiv">
        <p class="dataitemlabel">Delivery Date:</p>
        <input id="deldatetb" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="dataitemtextbox" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The Javascript:

```
function SearchOrder() {
    var OrderName = document.getElementById("SearchTextBox").value;
    var frurl = 'order/getbyname/' + OrderName;
    var api = new GetJSON(frurl);
    var obj;
    obj = api.CallAPI().done(function (data) {
        //alert('Quantity: '+data.Quantity +' & Delivery Date: ' + data.DeliveryDate);
        var onh = document.getElementById("OrderNameHeader");
            onh.title = data.OrderName;
        document.getElementById("quantitytb").value = data.Quantity;
        document.getElementById("deldatetb").value = data.DeliveryDate;
    });

}
```

Its worth noting at this point that the line: `alert('Quantity: '+data.Quantity +' & Delivery Date: ' + data.DeliveryDate);` works perfectly fine?

Do I have to do some manual refresh of the page in the Javascript or is there something else I am missing

**Update:**

Just to add some extra information, I've done some more debugging and I can see that neither the `data.~` or the element i'm trying to modify is `undefined`, they both have values.

Tested this on all major browsers (minus safari).
[image: debuginfo]

Comment: Yes, you can set value of readonly input, sorry for confusing you, I deleted my answer..

Comment: Is this failing on more than one browser?

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and IE its fails in

Comment: is it possible the statement onh = document... is assigning the value undefined to the variable, and you're dying on the assign statement?

Comment: @nril Just added some more info, but no, the value definitely isn't undefined. -I was kinda hoping it was, just to give me something to go off! :(

Comment: There is a title property on onh, but if I change onh.title to onh.textContent - at least the h1 value changes..